# Removing square brackets from output and stopping regex after first match

Tags: python, regex

Python noob here. I'm trying to fix two problems with my current code.

1. I'm trying to remove the square brackets from my list output
2. I can't figure out how to stop regex after the first match

For the first problem I've tried a number of different solutions but without success.

```
str()
"".join()
.replace"[]",''
```

```
page_content = "carrots apples001 carrots apples002 apples003"

define_words = 'apples'

parsed_content = str((re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s[^.]*\.)" % define_words, page_content)))
```

I'm currently getting the following output

`[apples001][][][][][apples002 apples003]`

When I should be getting

`apples001`

Any help would be much appreciated and sorry about the messy code!

Comment: So, basically, you want the first word starting with `define_words`?

Comment: Do you need to use regex for some reason?

Comment: @gmds I want to pull all of the terms with "apples" and the numbers that follow.

Comment: @db702 maybe not? that was the first solution that I found to parse through a PDF and return certain terms for my project

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Test_String = "carrots apples001 carrots apples002 apples003"
Regex_Pattern = r'(apples\S\S\S).*'
match = re.findall(Regex_Pattern, Test_String)
print(''.join(match))
```

[Rextester](https://rextester.com/QUQT49387)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), you could use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to search for the first location where the pattern produces a match.

To match the word apples and the following digits, you could use:

```
\bapples\d+\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent being part of a larger word
- `apples\d+` Match apples followed by 1+ digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a041Ln/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zw3wz5)

Your code could look like:

```
import re
page_content = "carrots apples001 carrots apples002 apples003"
define_words = 'apples'
parsed_content = (re.search(r"\b%s\d+\b" % define_words, page_content).group())
print(parsed_content)  # apples001
```

If define_words can start with a non word character, you might use `(?<!\S)%s\d+` instead to assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace character.

```
parsed_content = (re.search(r"(?<!\S)%s\d+" % define_words, page_content).group())
```